# Error in _ViewImports.cshtml The type or namespace name 'xxx' does not exist in the namespace 'yyy'

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am using RC2 of ASP.Net MVC Core.

I have added my using directives to _ViewImports and it is complaining that the namespace is incorrect. I use the exact same namespace in my controller and it works fine but will not work in the views.

The using directive is referencing a class library in the same solution.

```
@using xxx.Web
@using xxx.Web.Models
@using xxx.Web.Models.AccountViewModels
@using xxx.Web.Models.ManageViewModels
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using xxx.yyy
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

I have done significant research on the problem but it looks like it really should be as simple as adding the namespace. It even autocompletes in _ViewImports so I am not misspelling it (I have copied and pasted it just in case).

In case it is relevant I do use a "top Level" namespace so my web project is xxx.Web and my class library is xxx.yyy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this exact same problem, and found this question via Google. I solved it by ensuring that my class library was a `.NET Core/Class Library` rather than a `Windows/Class Library` (when using the "Add New Project" dialog). I ended up removing my old class library, creating a new project of the correct type, and adding my source files to it.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you have the latest version of ASP.NET Core, this could solve your problem:

```
 services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
  {
            var previous = options.CompilationCallback;
            options.CompilationCallback = (context) =>
            {
                previous?.Invoke(context);
                context.Compilation = context.Compilation.AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(hbulens.MyBucketList.Utilities.EnumUtilities).Assembly.Location));
            };
   });
```

or you can try:

```
services.Configure((RazorViewEngineOptions options) =>
{
  var previous = options.CompilationCallback;
   options.CompilationCallback = (context) =>
   {
      previous?.Invoke(context);  
      context.Compilation = context.Compilation.AddReferences(myAssemblies);
    };
});
```

Put this code in the ConfigureServices method of the startup class.